# Python pip cannot install zbarlight: error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, pip, python-3.5, zbar

First of all I installed Python 3.5.1:

```
yum -y install zbar gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel
./configure --enable-shared --prefix=/usr/local LDFLAGS="-Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/lib"
make && make install
```

Tried to install zbarlight pypi package but failed:

```
    src/zbarlight/_zbarlight.c:137: error: ‘ZBAR_QRCODE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    src/zbarlight/_zbarlight.c:138: error: ‘ZBAR_CODE128’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ur77y560/zbarlight/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-hoalto9f-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ur77y560/zbarlight/
```

How do I fix that? I tried pip3.5 -v but doesn't show any more meaningful error.

Answer (score 0):

Had to install

```
yum install zbar-devel
```